# nmap - No Ports Open

Tags: penetration-test, vulnerability, nmap, scan

I bought a Tonbux Smart WiFi Plug WL-SC01 and I'm doing some hack tests on it for educational purposes. I used nmap to check for both UDP and TCP ports but both return that there are no open ports at all. Ping shows that the device is up on the Local Lan. any further ideas to try and see if there are any open ports?

Comment: Did you run nmap with `-p1-65535` or only with the default set of ports?

Comment: I would scan another IP on the network with exact same nmap syntax to see if it works in principle.  Then if your syntax is correct and your plug has no open ports, I would deduct that something is blocking all connections from your nmap PC except for ICMP/ping.  It could be your wireless access point or router or the device itself.

Comment: When posting questions about running commands/tools, it is most helpful if you included the full command/configuration so that we can see how you ran it. Else, all we can say is "well, if you ran that command, that's all you need to do."